# Is the TestFlight app available for users in mainland China?

Tags: ios, testflight

I am getting ready to push a build on TestFlight to end-users who will reside in mainland China and/or Hong Kong. I am looking for confirmation that TestFlight will work in these locations and users have the same experience of going through their TestFlight app on iPad and iPhone to download and use my app. Can someone help provide me with this confirmation?

Thanks for all the help,
Ajay

Comment: ofcouurse it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Have you launched any apps in China using TestFlight? I am looking for any lessons, steps I need to keep in mind and so on.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the app page](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8) for TestFlight by Apple in China, so I would think that the service is available as well.

I've used TestFlight with testers in several different countries around the world without issue so long as they have the app downloaded.

[image]